# Standard Deviation Question

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

[image]

[image]

My working out:

Median = mean = 60

Q3 = 25% of values at 75

25% = 0.25 = z-score of 0.68

Sx = (75-60)/0.68 = 22.3881 approx = 20... I said D

The correct answer is B. 10

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, for a normal distribution $95$ % should be within a distance of $2\sigma$ from the mean. What value of $\sigma$ makes approximately $95$ % fall in the interval $[60-2\sigma, \, 60+2\sigma]$?

Comment: I'm confused how to link an interval of 95% with [60-2σ)

Comment: @confused Okay, it's because the 2.5th percentile in the normal distribution is at a distance of $-1.96\sigma$ from the mean. So you have 2.5 % below this point. Since it's symmetric, beyond $1.96\sigma$ you also have 2.5 %. So in a normal distribution, 95 % is within a distance of $1.96\sigma$ from the mean, for which you can use 2 instead of 1.96 as an approximation. There is actually a wikipedia page about it with some nice illustrations that might be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule